# How to properly configure method in Web Api for JSON Post?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to update/save data to DB, but faced with a problem: 
While testing in Postman, I checked this JSON:

```
{
"contactId": "1",
"contactName": "t4jnesfdv",
"company": {
  "companyName":"a546fghf"
   }
}
```

It update/save selected record in table Contact, but also add new record to other table Company.

While testing in Postman, I checked this JSON:

```
{
"contactId": "1",
"contactName": "t4jnesfdv",
"company": {
           "companyId":"2",
           "companyName":"a546fghf"
      }
}
```

Get 500 Internal Server Error.

Interface

```
public interface IContactService
{
    Task<bool> SaveContact(ContactModel contact);
}
```

Service

```
public async Task<bool> SaveContact(ContactModel contactModel)
{
    using (ContactDBContext db = new ContactDBContext())
    {
        Contacts contact = db.Contacts.Where
                 (x => x.ContactId == contactModel.ContactId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contact == null)
        {

            contact = new Contacts()
            {
                ContactName = contactModel.ContactName,
                Company = contactModel.Company
            };
            db.Contacts.Add(contact);

        }
        else
        {
            contact.ContactName = contactModel.ContactName;
            contact.Company = contactModel.Company;
        }

        return await db.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SaveContact")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveContact([FromBody] ContactModel model)
    {
        return Ok(await _contactService.SaveContact(model));
    }
}
```

Models

```
public class CompanyModel
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
public class ContactModel
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Entities

```
public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
public class Contacts
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

I expect to save/update records in table Contact with existing companies in table Company, without adding new records to table Company

Comment: Can you post your `ContactModel` class ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the application where does the error occur, is the end point actually getting hit at all? Your model seems to match up fine with the JSON

Comment: @Michael I got this SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Company' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: You get 500 error when you send request?Did you register `IContactService` in Startup.cs?

Comment: Does a company with ID 2 exist? The issue is here Entity Framework is trying to add a company record but with IDENTITY_INSERT on you cant pass an ID as these values are auto incremented in the database

Comment: @Rena Yes, sure `services.AddTransient<IContactService, ContactService>();`

Comment: @Michael yes, I read a lot about this issue, but in my case, I do not want to update the table Companies, I need update records only in the table Contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my Contact Entity and Model (and update db):

```
public class Contacts
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public Company Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

Rewrote Service:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveContact(ContactModel contactModel)
        {
            using (ContactDBContext db = new ContactDBContext())
            {
                Contacts contact = db.Contacts.Where
                         (x => x.ContactId == contactModel.ContactId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (contact == null)
                {
                        contact = new Contacts()
                    {
                        ContactName = contactModel.ContactName,
                        CompanyId = contactModel.CompanyId
                };
                    db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                    }
                else
                {
                    contact.ContactName = contactModel.ContactName;
                    contact.CompanyId = contactModel.CompanyId;
                }

                return await db.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1;
            }
        }
```

And tested my Web Api in Postman with this JSON:

```
{
        "contactId": 2,
        "contactName": "1try93445",
        "companyId": "7"
    }
```

All worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Company** is the child table in your database so in case of update you should first fetch that company object from database and then update its value by using its object

```
Contacts contact = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactId == contactModel.ContactId).FirstOrDefault();

Company company = db.Companies.Where(x => x.ContactId == contactModel.ContactId).FirstOrDefault();

 contact.ContactName = contactModel.ContactName;
 contact.Company.CompanyName = contactModel.Company.CompanyName;
```

Comment: I have relation between table Contacts and Company like one to many. `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Contacts)
        .WithOne(e => e.Company);`

Comment: OK then u have to iterate through a loop and assign each value and after that u can directly call savechanges() method

Comment: As i can see you have company as a base object and contact as child of company, so one company can have multiple contacts, so first correct your json object, create company as a object and create array of contacts in company.

Comment: do u want to update single object of contact or multiple object?

Comment: I want to update table Contacts (I has field ContactId, ContactName and CompanyId) in my DB and change there field CompanyId `{
"contactId": "2",
"contactName": "23424",
"company": {
 "companyId": 1
}
}`

Comment: i have add one more solution below

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public async Task<bool> SaveContact(ContactModel contactModel)
    {
        using (ContactDBContext db = new ContactDBContext())
        {
            Contacts contact = db.Contacts.Where
                     (x => x.ContactId == contactModel.ContactId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (contact == null)
            {

                contact = new Contacts()
                {
                    ContactName = contactModel.ContactName,
                    Company = contactModel.Company
                };
                db.Contacts.Add(contact);

            }
            else
            {
                contact.ContactName = contactModel.ContactName;
                contact.Company.CompanyId = contactModel.Company.CompanyId;
            }

            return await db.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have alredy tried that, but got 500 Internal Server Error